# Which hormonal treatments have been shown to be useful to prevent or treat tendinopathies?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, endocrinology

Which hormonal treatments have been shown to be useful to prevent or treat tendinopathies?

{1} surveyed the links between hormones and tendinopathies but their main conclusion is:

> The influence of hormones on tendon structure and metabolism needs to be further investigated. If found to be significant, multidisciplinary preventive and therapeutic strategies should then be developed.

{2} is a good example of what kind of hormonal treatment recommendations there could be: they showed that oral contraceptives provide protection against anterior cruciate ligament tears based on a national database study of 165,748 female patients.

---

References:

- {1} Oliva, Francesco, Eleonora Piccirilli, Anna C. Berardi, Antonio Frizziero, Umberto Tarantino, and Nicola Maffulli. "Hormones and tendinopathies: the current evidence." British medical bulletin 117, no. 1 (2016): 39-58. ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Hormones+and+tendinopathies%3A+the+current+evidence+&btnG=#d=gs_cit&u=%2Fscholar%3Fq%3Dinfo%3AA479fpViazoJ%3Ascholar.google.com%2F%26output%3Dcite%26scirp%3D0%26hl%3Den ; https://doi.org/10.1093/bmb/ldv054
- {2} DeFroda, Steven F., Steven L. Bokshan, Samatha Worobey, Lauren Ready, Alan H. Daniels, and Brett D. Owens. "Oral contraceptives provide protection against anterior cruciate ligament tears: a national database study of 165,748 female patients." The Physician and sportsmedicine just-accepted (2019). ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Oral+contraceptives+provide+protection+against+anterior+cruciate+ligament+tears%3A+a+national+database+study+of+165%2C748+female+patients&btnG= ; https://doi.org/10.1080/00913847.2019.1600334